# How to set org context in Oracle Apps R12 in back-end in case of multiple org-id?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I have executed the query for single org-id and it is working properly.

begin
mo_global.set_policy_context('S',204);
end;

But for multiple cases I executed the following queries but it is not working

begin
mo_global.set_policy_context('M',204);
end;

Even I tried running this-
begin
mo_global.set_policy_context('M',null);
end;

I just want to know the 2nd parameter in case of multiple org-id.

Answer (score 3):

a simple and failsafe call for multiple org init is:

```
exec mo_global.init('M');
```

and for single:

```
exec mo_global.init('S');
```

Explanation: mo_global.init checks the application_short_name parameter against table fnd_mo_product_init and decides by the table's status column to proceed further with multiple or single org logic.

If the application_short_name parameter passed is not registered in that table, mo_global.init will fail.
Oracle added the dummy short names 'M' and 'S' to fnd_mo_product_init to allow calling the procedure without a real apps name.

Answer (score 2):

--Initialization of view

```
mo_global.set_policy_context(S,org_id)
```

if we know the user id, rep id, and app_resp_id then we can use the below query

```
fnd_globa.apps_initialize(:p_user_id, :p_resp_id, :p_app_resp_id);
```

Comment: Please format your source code using backticks, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more informations. It's justa regular markdown, so should be easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use exec MO_GLOBAL.INIT('Give Application name');